# Python text clustering software or package

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, nltk

For my project, I need to cluster some text (English text). I am okay with any clustering algorithm like [k-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) or [hierarchical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering). The only thing is I also need the cluster to be named by the software, so that the text's clusters have different names.

Is this possible?

Comment: What kind of names are you expecting.

Comment: I mean if I give some text related to investment, then it is classified into investment by itself.

Comment: I have no experience with it but `Nltk` have a [`Cluster`](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.cluster.html) package.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is software that can name the clusters

```
cluster_1
cluster_2
cluster_3
cluster_4
```

Seriously **what do you *expect* the cluster names to be**? An automatic summary from the clustered articles? Text summarization isn't scaling up too well yet. But you could probably try to run the complete cluster through a text summarization engine.

Note that k-means will produce quite artificial clusters. It doesn't know or care about topics. It just optimizes mathematical variance, which probably is not very useful for text data.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is: cluster the words using an off-the-shelf clustering algorithm, then run some algorithm that inspects each cluster to find the word(s) that are somehow indicative of that cluster. There are lots of options for doing that, but the first thing that comes to mind is doing a good old [chi² test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) between the cluster and each terms, then pick the terms with the highest test statistic value.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what your goals are, or what your data looks like. (A list of wordcounts per passage? Something else?)

For starters, then, I would recommend separating the data collection/ preparation from the analysis. In particular, you'll want a package with a pre-defined clustering implementation that makes exploratory analysis feasible, and the straight-out code implementations are often a little too bare bones. Consider using something with integrated visualization and data presentation capabilities to help you better understand the meaning of your clusters: predefined packages like [R](http://www.r-project.org/) (statistics software), MATLAB, or [Orange](http://orange.biolab.si/) (python-based data mining suite) are all good choices.

Orange has a lot of really nice GUI options to control how clusters are selected (distance metric, iterations, etc), and it also provides a few different ways to explore which clusters are most useful. However, at least as of a year ago, my experience is that its implementation of k-means clustering was laughably slow on a midsize (800 MB) data set. Some of that will be due to the fact that python is inherently slower than other languages, but I suspect that there are other issues as well. Whatever you use, you'll need to be sure to look at the input file documentation carefully.